# Foundation 6 - have multiple stacked-for breakpoints in a single top-bar

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation, responsive, zurb-foundation-6

I have a top-bar menu using foundation 6.
Essentially it is the same as the example one from Foundation relating to stacking breakpoints., except that I have aded a third section for a logo.

[See this forked pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eVgOxo)

code below :

```html
<div class="top-bar">
  <div class="top-bar-left stacked-for-large">
    <div class="top-bar-title">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x40">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="top-bar stacked-for-medium">
    <div class="top-bar-left">
      <ul class="dropdown menu" data-dropdown-menu>
        <li class="menu-text">Site Title</li>
        <li class="has-submenu">
          <a href="#0">One</a>
          <ul class="submenu menu vertical" data-submenu>
            <li><a href="#0">One</a></li>
            <li><a href="#0">Two</a></li>
            <li><a href="#0">Three</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#0">Two</a></li>
        <li><a href="#0">Three</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="top-bar-right">
      <ul class="menu">
        <li><input type="search" placeholder="Search"></li>
        <li><button type="button" class="button">Search</button></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now as you can see this stacks the 3 elements on medium screens, as per the stacked-for-medium class.

What I want to achieve, and have had no success in doing so, is to have 2 different stacking breakpoints.

Namely stacked-for-large on : one + (two + three)

And stacked-for-medium on : one + two + three.

(one/two/three refer to the elements with those IDs)

To clarify I expect it to go as follows as one downsizes their browser :

one two three

---

one

two three

---

one

two

three

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much searching it appears the short answer is that it is not possible using Foundation top-bar functions. So I needed to rewrite my own.

The key to solving it is to use media queries combined with the correct DIV nesting, to snap elements to the correct locations at the correct times, much like how Foundation handles top-bar's itself, only for this specific breakpoint pattern.

Two + Three are contained within a greater element with drops below the logo at a specified point. Then as the screeen shrinks even more, they also drop below one another.

Note: this still uses Foundation's top-bar code for correct stacking of the menu itself within "two".

[Code pen here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eVgqxG)

```js
$(document).foundation();
```

```css
.topbar {
  background : aquamarine;
}
.topbar-logo {
  width: 274px;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  
  border: 1px solid;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1000px){
  .topbar-main-container {
    min-width: 1000px;
    float: left;
  }
  .topbar-right{
    float: right;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 999.99px){
  .topbar-right{
    float: left;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 700px) {
  topbar-main{
    min-width: 700px;
/*     width: calc(100% - 300px - 10px); */
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 699.99px) {
  topbar-main{
    float: left;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1274px){
  .topbar-main-container {
    width: calc(100% - 274px);

  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1273.99px){
  .topbar-main-container {
    width: 100%;
    clear: both;
  }
}
.topbar-main {
  float: left;
  
  border: 1px solid;
}
.topbar-right{
  width: 350px;
  height: 50px;
  
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.4.3/css/foundation.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.4.3/js/foundation.min.js"></script>
<div class="row expanded topbar">
  <div class="topbar-logo" id="one">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x40">
  </div>
  <div class="topbar-main-container">
    <div class="topbar-main top-bar-left" id="two">
      <ul class="dropdown menu simple vertical medium-horizontal" data-dropdown-menu>
        <li class="menu-text">Site Title</li>
        <li class="has-submenu">
          <a href="#0">One</a>
          <ul class="submenu menu vertical" data-submenu>
            <li><a href="#0">One</a></li>
            <li><a href="#0">Two</a></li>
            <li><a href="#0">Three</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#0">Two</a></li>
        <li><a href="#0">Three</a></li>
        <li><a href="#0">Two</a></li>
        <li><a href="#0">Three</a></li>
        <li><a href="#0">Two</a></li>
        <li><a href="#0">Three</a></li>
        <li><a href="#0">Two</a></li>
        <li><a href="#0">Three</a></li>
        
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="topbar-right" id="three">
      Some names and stuff
    </div>    
  </div>
</div>
```